# How can I prevent it from slipping when I use NavMeshAgent?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've written a simple short code using agent.destination from the NavMesh Agent that allows enemies to track players. However, in the process of chasing the target, the enemy keeps slipping and not chasing properly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using static UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventTrigger;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public Transform runAwayPos;
    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public Transform spwanPosition;

    void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Run());
        if (Time.timeScale == 0)
        {
            transform.position = spwanPosition.position;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Run()
    {
        agent.speed = 9f;
        agent.destination = target.transform.position;
        yield return null;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            transform.position = spwanPosition.position;
            Debug.Log("hit");
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder how the enemy can track a player without slipping.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "slipping" or provide a video of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you call IEnumarator per frame. this causes unwanted consequences.Use either update or IEnumarator.

In my opininon,

```
void Update()
    {
      agent.SetDestination(target.position);

        if (Time.timeScale == 0)
        {
            transform.position = spwanPosition.position;
        }
    }
```

By the way, you should use a boolean to check the untracked case.